# In Qt framework, how to make an autoexpanding QPlainTextEdit widget?

Tags: qt, pyside6, pyqt6

I would like to have a `QPlainTextEdit` widget that initially has height of one line (when it is empty). When user adds more text to the widget, it should automatically change its height to avoid scrolling.

How can I do that? I myself use `PySide6`, but C++ code is fine, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow me to answer since you accept C++ code. Editing my initial answer to simplify the code (thanks @musicamante for the suggestion; it was even more simple than you commented) + address 2 flaws of my previous answer:

- Getting the width of the plain text edit was not detailed (which is not easy to do when it is first shown on screen).
- I overlooked the posibility that the plain text edit width could be changed (making more or less text fit in each line).

**Step 1: Event filter**

In Qt, getting the size widgets before they are shown on screen is hard; instead, we aim at getting the size when the plain text edit is shown for the first time.

To do that and to keep track of subsequent size changes, we first need an event filter class.

```cpp
#include <QtCore/QObject.h>
#include <QtGui/QEvent.h>

class SizeEventFilter : public QObject {
Q_OBJECT
public:
    SizeEventFilter(QObject* parent) : QObject(parent) {}
protected:
    bool eventFilter(QObject* obj, QEvent* event)
    {
        if (event->type() == QEvent::Resize)
            emit sizeChanged(obj);
        return false;
    }
signals:
    void sizeChanged(QObject* object);
};
```

**Step 2: Height calculation lambda**

We use a lambda to recalculate the size of `plainTextEdit`. The lambda uses 2 additional variables in its capture list, the definition of which I included below.

```cpp
auto margins = plainTextEdit->contentsMargins();
auto margin = plainTextEdit->document()->rootFrame()->frameFormat().margin();
qreal verticalmarginSize = 2 * margin + margins.top() + margins.bottom();

QFont font = plainTextEdit->font();
QFontMetrics fontMetrics(font);
int lineHeight = fontMetrics.lineSpacing();

auto sizeCalculation = [plainTextEdit, lineHeight, verticalmarginSize]() {
    auto document = plainTextEdit->document();
    auto size = document->size();
    int height = lineHeight * size.height() + verticalmarginSize + 1;
    if (height != plainTextEdit->height())
        plainTextEdit->setFixedHeight(height);
};
```

**Step 3: Making everything work together**

Right after the above code (step 2), insert the event filter, the connections and some tweaking of `plainTextEdit` as shown below.
If you want to change the font of `plainTextEdit`, as it is used in the capture list of the lambda, you must add the line before calling `QFont font = plainTextEdit->font();`.

```cpp
QObject::connect(plainTextEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, sizeCalculation);

SizeEventFilter* sizeEventFilter = new SizeEventFilter(plainTextEdit);
plainTextEdit->installEventFilter(sizeEventFilter);
QObject::connect(sizeEventFilter, &SizeEventFilter::sizeChanged, plainTextEdit, sizeCalculation, Qt::QueuedConnection);

plainTextEdit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
plainTextEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
```

**A problem remains...**

In a more complete example, there are situations where several `QPlainTextEdit` in a layout interfere with one another.

The scenario is as follow:

1. Several `QPlainTextEdit` are added to a `QScrollArea`. The `verticalBarPolicy` property is set to `Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded`.
   Due to their text, the scrollbar is hidden but with just 1 more line in any of them, it would need to be shown.

[image: When the window is opened]

2. A line is added to one of the `QPlainTextEdit`. The scrollbar appears, adding an additional line break elsewhere.

[image: 1 line is added; a scrollbar appears.]

3. The line is later removed, however, the state does not revert to what it was on step 1: the additional line break does not disappear, that is unless we put in some extra effort.

[image: The inserted line is removed but the scrollbar remains.]

I have put up the below full example to demonstrate this effect.
The code uses what I presented above and behaves like the way shown in the screenshots.
If you remove the portion I marked with comments and uncomment the lines under that portion, you will get a more correct behavior, where the layout is recalculated without the vertical scrollbar just to see if it fits.

```cpp
#include <QtGui/QFontMetrics>
#include <QtGui/QTextDocument>
#include <QtGui/QTextFrame>

#include <QtWidgets/QApplication>
#include <QtWidgets/QBoxLayout>
#include <QtWidgets/QScrollArea>
#include <QtWidgets/QPlainTextEdit>

#include "SizeEventFilter.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    app.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);

    auto main_widget = new QWidget();
    main_widget->setMinimumSize(800, 410);

    QScrollArea* scroll_area = new QScrollArea();
    QWidget* scroll_widget = new QWidget();
    QVBoxLayout* scroll_vbox = new QVBoxLayout(scroll_widget);

    scroll_vbox->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
    scroll_vbox->setSpacing(0);
    scroll_widget->setLayout(scroll_vbox);


    scroll_area->setWidget(scroll_widget);
    scroll_area->setWidgetResizable(true);

    auto vbox0 = new QVBoxLayout(main_widget);
    main_widget->setLayout(vbox0);
    vbox0->addWidget(scroll_area);

    QPlainTextEdit
        * plainTextEdit0 = new QPlainTextEdit(),
        * plainTextEdit1 = new QPlainTextEdit(),
        * plainTextEdit2 = new QPlainTextEdit();
    plainTextEdit1->setPlainText("A looooooooooooooooong text carefully tailored to fit exactly in 1 line of text, and without leaving enough space for the scrollbar exactly here.");
    plainTextEdit2->setPlainText("line 1\nline 2\r\nline 3\nline 4\nline 5\nline 6\nline 7\nline 8\nline 9\nline 10\nline 11\nline 12\nline 13\nline 14\nline 15\nline 16\nline 17\nline 18\nline 19\nline 20");

    for (auto plainTextEdit : { plainTextEdit0, plainTextEdit1, plainTextEdit2 }) {
        scroll_vbox->addWidget(plainTextEdit);


        auto margins = plainTextEdit->contentsMargins();
        auto margin = plainTextEdit->document()->rootFrame()->frameFormat().margin();
        qreal verticalmarginSize = 2 * margin + margins.top() + margins.bottom();

        QFont font = plainTextEdit->font();
        QFontMetrics fontMetrics(font);
        int lineHeight = fontMetrics.lineSpacing();
        

        // Portion with the incorrect behavior -> To be removed
        auto sizeCalculation = [plainTextEdit, lineHeight, verticalmarginSize]() {
            auto document = plainTextEdit->document();
            auto size = document->size();
            int height = lineHeight * size.height() + verticalmarginSize + 1;
            if (height != plainTextEdit->height())
                plainTextEdit->setFixedHeight(height);
        };
        QObject::connect(plainTextEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, sizeCalculation);

        SizeEventFilter* sizeEventFilter = new SizeEventFilter(plainTextEdit);
        plainTextEdit->installEventFilter(sizeEventFilter);
        QObject::connect(sizeEventFilter, &SizeEventFilter::sizeChanged, plainTextEdit, sizeCalculation, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        // End of Portion with the incorrect behavior
        
        //// Better behavior -> To be uncommented
        //auto sizeCalculation1 = [plainTextEdit, scroll_vbox, lineHeight, verticalmarginSize]()
        //{
        //    auto document = plainTextEdit->document();
        //    auto size = document->size();
        //    int height = lineHeight * size.height() + verticalmarginSize + 1;
        //    if (height != plainTextEdit->height())
        //        plainTextEdit->setFixedHeight(height);
        //    scroll_vbox->invalidate();
        //    scroll_vbox->activate();
        //};
        //auto sizeCalculation2 = [plainTextEdit, scroll_area, scroll_vbox, lineHeight, verticalmarginSize]()
        //{
        //    auto document = plainTextEdit->document();
        //    auto size = document->size();
        //    int height = lineHeight * size.height() + verticalmarginSize + 1;
        //    bool tryWithoutScrollBar = height < plainTextEdit->height() && scroll_area->verticalScrollBarPolicy() == Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded;

        //    if (tryWithoutScrollBar) {
        //        scroll_area->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        //        scroll_vbox->invalidate();
        //        //scroll_vbox->update();
        //        scroll_vbox->activate();
        //        document = plainTextEdit->document();
        //        size = document->size();
        //        height = lineHeight * size.height() + verticalmarginSize + 1;
        //        plainTextEdit->setFixedHeight(height);
        //        scroll_area->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAsNeeded);
        //        scroll_vbox->invalidate();
        //        //scroll_vbox->update();
        //        scroll_vbox->activate();
        //    }
        //    else if (height != plainTextEdit->height())
        //        plainTextEdit->setFixedHeight(height);
        //};

        //QObject::connect(plainTextEdit, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged, sizeCalculation2);

        //SizeEventFilter* sizeEventFilter = new SizeEventFilter(plainTextEdit);
        //plainTextEdit->installEventFilter(sizeEventFilter);
        //QObject::connect(sizeEventFilter, &SizeEventFilter::sizeChanged, plainTextEdit, sizeCalculation1, Qt::QueuedConnection);
        //QObject::connect(sizeEventFilter, &SizeEventFilter::sizeChanged, plainTextEdit, sizeCalculation2, Qt::DirectConnection);
        //// End of better behavior

        plainTextEdit->setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
        plainTextEdit->setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(Qt::ScrollBarAlwaysOff);
    }
    scroll_vbox->addSpacerItem(new QSpacerItem(0, 0, QSizePolicy::Minimum, QSizePolicy::MinimumExpanding));

    main_widget->show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

This turned out to be a lengthy answer, sorry for that...

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to clone the QTextDocument and just use `setTextWidth()` to get its layout processed and having the proper height with the document `size()`? I know that creating a whole new QTextDocument is not the same as using a QTextLayout, but if the OP is actually going to implement this in python, iterating through the whole text could actually result in worse performances considering the bottleneck of the python binding.

Comment: The issue with the vertical scroll bar is difficult to avoid, and is one of the problems with scroll areas that have scroll bars that change the viewport size. There are a few options, but none is optimal: 1. always show the vertical scroll bar (simple, effective, but not very good looking); 2. use/implement a style that supports transient scroll bars (difficult, and I never liked that behavior a lot); 3. let the scroll area manage the height of the text edits, so that it can compute the possible height *not* including the scroll bar and eventually apply it if it fits the full height.

Comment: The third method is probably the best, but it obviously has the limitation that the subclass can only be used for this specific case, with no other widget types (especially not those with expanding size policies) except those for which it has complete control of their sizes. For instance, using QLabels with word wrapping (or HTML) would make this almost impossible, due to the known issue with their size hint in complex layouts.

Comment: I implemented a not too ugly way to adress this without revisiting the structure of the window.

Comment: @Atmo, wow, thank you very much for such an amazing answer!!!

Comment: I should say that I use macOS and PySide6 with version 6.4.2. On this version, the correct behavior is already with only one handler `sizeCalculation`. Actually, switching to two handlers does not lead to any visible changes for me.

Comment: I suppose there could be OS differences here and there. On Windows, Qt 6.5.0, the `resizeEvent` requires a separate connection; even adding `Qt::SingleShotConnection` to the queued connection stops it from working, which in turn forced me to ensure I do not touch the layout in the event loop, hence the 2 lambdas.

Answer (score 1):

try this one if u want ---  initial one line  , auto change height

```
int main8(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QPlainTextEdit w;
    auto func = [&]() {
        int lineCount = w.document()->lineCount() + 1;
        QFontMetrics fm(w.font());
        int lineSpacing = fm.lineSpacing();
        int height = lineCount * lineSpacing;

        w.setFixedHeight(height);
    };
    QObject::connect(&w, &QPlainTextEdit::textChanged,func);
    w.show();
    func();
    return a.exec();
    
}
```

I take it from [enter link description here](https://forum.qt.io/topic/45645/qplaintextedit-set-height-based-on-text-pasted-in)

Comment: Note that this doesn't take into account the [`documentMargin()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtextdocument.html#documentMargin-prop) nor the frame (usually, the widget's `contentsMargins()`). You're trying to fix it by adding a line, but that's not an accurate computation.

Comment: Thank you! It works basically always! For some reason, it does not work on paste into an empty textarea (it works, when it is not empty) and on window resize. I have also ended with height calculation as `height = lineCount * lineSpace + margins + 2 * doc_margin + 1`, where `margins = w.contentMargins().top() + w.contentMargins().bottom()`, `doc_margin = w.document().documentMargin()`, and 1 must be added to avoid a vertical scroll line in the empty one-line textarea.